# How can I tell my laptop to shutodwn after finishing running a non-root process

Tags: password, sudo, shutdown

I'd like to be able to say:

```
./run_process.sh; sudo shutdown -P now
```

but the call to sudo will ask for my password and then my laptop won't shut down because it's waiting for my password.  How can I pre-supply the password to sudo when I enter the command (but still run ./run_process.sh from my user account without sudo)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do some "reverse psychology" here:

```
sudo bash -c "sudo -u dspyz ./run_process.sh; shutdown -P now"
```

i.e. run sudo, then "unsudo" to your process as your self (where `dspyz` is your user name on that system), not as root, and then shutdown under the original sudo.

You can try this to see what it will do:

```
sudo bash -c 'sudo -u dspyz id; echo `id`'
```

where `id` command shows the current user's ID and will be your (i.e. `dspyz`'s ID for the first `id`, which plays the role of `./run_process.sh`, but will be `root` for the second `id`, which plays the role of `shutdown -P now`).

Hope this helps.